# There is an extra id column in dataFrame read from csv

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I created a `dataFrame` and it's the output:

```
print(train_df)

           author                                               text
0   BernardHickey  The Commmonwealth Bank of Australia (CBA) warn...
1   BernardHickey  Rupert Murdoch predicted in a newspaper interv...
2   BernardHickey  News Corp Ltd chairman and chief executive Rup...
3   BernardHickey  Rupert Murdoch on Tuesday reported that News C...
4   BernardHickey  Rupert Murdoch on Tuesday reported that News C...
```

Then I saved the data frame:

```
train_df.to_csv(data_path+'/train.csv')
```

When I read it again:

```
data = pd.read_csv(data_path+'/train.csv')
data.head(10)

Unnamed: 0  author  text
0   0   BernardHickey   The Commmonwealth Bank of Australia (CBA) warn...
1   1   BernardHickey   Rupert Murdoch predicted in a newspaper interv...
2   2   BernardHickey   News Corp Ltd chairman and chief executive Rup...
3   3   BernardHickey   Rupert Murdoch on Tuesday reported that News C...
```

Why is there an `Unnamed` column there? How can I avoid it?

Comment: Yep, set `index=False` when you write the CSV...

Comment: you need to pass `index=False` flag when saving to `csv`

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem!